# A proper way of comparing unequal char arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, compare

Is there a proper way of comparing two char-arrays if they aren't equal by length?
How to check which character isn't equal?

strcmp seems to give me only bigger or lesser number, not the position of unequal character.

For example, strings:

```
/home/jjjj/ and
/home/jjjj/kkkk/asdasd
```

Should return 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `strlen()` and `strstr()` you can achieves this in a two-step approach:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...


char str1[] = "this is a long string";
char str2[] = "long";

{
  char * ss = NULL;
  char * sg = NULL;
  size_t size1 = strlen(str1)
  size_t size2 = strlen(str2);
  size_t size_ss = 0;

  /* step 1: determine which of the two strings tobe compared it the smaller/greater one. */
  if (size1 > size2)
  {
    size_ss = size2;
    ss = str2;
    sg = str1;
  }
  else
  {
    size_ss = size1;
    ss = str1;
    sg = str2;
  }

  /* step 2: find out where the smaller string is located in the greater one, if ever... */
  {
    char * p = strstr(sg, ss);

    if (p)
    {
      printf("'%s' is the same as '%s' from character %zu to character %zu.\n", 
        sg, ss, p - sg, p - sg + size_ss);
    }
    else
    {
      /* printf("The strings are 100%% differently!\n"); */ /* changed as per Jonathan's comment. */
      printf("'%s' does not appear in '%s'.\n", ss, sg);
    }
  }
}
```

This solution does not take into account that the shorter string could appear more than once in the longer string. It always notifies about the first occurrence.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that if I have two strings "abc" and "abd", these strings are reported as 100% different?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, that's been another good example for an imprecise, to not say wrong "error" message. Thank you for giving me the chance to correct this.

Comment: The OP asked for a string comparison from the start of the string. This answer gives a solution for a string search of the shorter within the longer string. The OP accepted it because it happens to work for his given example. If this is homework, then either the question was imprecise, or the OP is going for a bad surprise when the teacher evaluates it... ;)

Comment: @Secure: "*The OP asked for a string comparison from the start of the string.*",  did he?

Comment: @alk: He asked about "comparing", not about "searching", even giving `strcmp` as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a standard C function that returns the first point of discrepancy between two strings.

It wouldn't be hard to create one; take a version of `strcmp()` from a text book and modify it so that returns the offset of the strings at the point where the result is 'interesting'.  If the strings are equal, that will be the offset of the null terminator (`'\0'`); otherwise, it will be the offset where the two strings are different.

Comment: Or if you don't think C++-esque but C-esque, then you return `NULL` if they are equal and the pointer to the different character if they aren't :)

Comment: The trouble with returning a pointer is that a pointer is asymmetric. Which of the two strings is the pointer pointing at?  You also have to do extra computation to find the correct character in the other string.  An offset is neutral between the two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
const char* strcmp_plusplus (const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
  const char* result = NULL; // return NULL if equal

  while(*str1 != '\0')
  {
    if(*str1 != *str2)
    {
      result = str1;  // point at where in str1 they are different
      break;
    }

    str1++;
    str2++;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Note that we won't have to check if str2 is `\0`, because the C standard allows us to read one element beyond an array without invoking undefined behavior. If str2 ends before str1, the function will return a pointer to str1's null termination.

Comment: The nul byte is part of the object, so you won't read beyond the array.

Comment: @wildplasser Hmm yes you are correct. If str1 points at something inside its string and str2 at `\0', the iteration will still stop.

Comment: If the strings are both 32 bytes long, say, and differ in the first byte, your code still scans the other bytes in the string before the loop terminates.  You could do `return result;` in the conditional inside the loop, and then simply `return NULL` at the end, rendering `result` unnecessary as a variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah yeah of course. Turns out I should test code before posting it here :) I meant to have a break in there. The purpose of the result variable is to only have one return statement in the function, since multiple return statements are sometimes considered as spaghetti programming. It will be optimized away in the machine code anyhow. Updated post.

Answer (score 0):

This function attempts to do it all at once. Since a function can only return one value, one of the resulting values (the difference) has to be passed back to the caller via a pointer to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t lead_cmp( const char * one, const char * two, int *result);
size_t lead_cmp( const char * one, const char * two, int *result)
{
    size_t pos;

    for(pos=0; one[pos] && two[pos]; pos++) {
        if (one[pos] != two[pos]) break;
    }

    *result = one[pos] - two[pos];
    return pos;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t len;
    int diff;

    len = lead_cmp (argv[1], argv[2], &diff );
    printf( "Pos=%zu, Rc=%d\n", len, diff);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./a.out /home/jjjj/ /home/jjjj/kkkk/
Pos=11, Rc=-107
$
```

The found position is 11, not 12, since C uses 0-based indexing.

It returns the number of matching characters: the length of the common prefix.